# Changing the way \over is defined

Tags: math-mode

I would like to be able to type things like `$1/2$` instead of `$\frac{1}{2}$` as this would make my code better readable. For longer equations I prefer to use `\frac{}{}`, but for things like `1/2` I don't like it.

This does the trick in some sense:

```
\catcode`/ = 13
\def/{\over}
```

But I don't really like the way `\over` works. Is it possible to redefine `\over` such that `ab\over cd` is interpreted as `a\frac{b}{c}d`? And such that `{ab}\over{cd}` is interpreted as `\frac{ab}{cd}`?

---

I know it is recommended to not use `\over`, but as `\frac` is a definition based on `\over` I thought that it may be possible to write another definition based on `\over` that give less problems than `\over`, but keeps the infix notation.

Comment: @Mico I don't want to change the definition of `\over`. I want to have a new definition say `\newover` that works like I described and then use `\catcode\`/ = 13 \def/{\newover}` so that I can type `1/2` instead of `\frac{1}{2}`

Comment: you can copy the definition of `\frac` but I'm sure that this will make some other package break down if not scoped properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying here. How can it help me to copy the definition of `\frac` ?

Comment: at the macro level there is no way to go back and pick something which came _before_. You can do `\def\Over #1/#2{\frac {#1}{#2}}`, and then make some character mathematically active (no need to make it catcode active in the whole document), let's say for example the `@` and then your input will be `$@3/2a+@5/3b$`.

Comment: This would be a bad idea even if it were doable. Your code will *not* be more readable. However, you would need `${1/2}+{1/3}={5/6}$` anyway, because of how `\over` works.

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, the issue with the `\over` macro -- and similar TeX "primitive" commands, such as `\choose` and `\atop` -- is *precisely* that its infix notation lends itself to creating serious accidents unless its syntax is obeyed perfectly. This is, presumably, why the LaTeX macro `\frac` was created in the first place: to act as a carefully crafted "wrapper" macro around `\over`.

If you're confident you can handle `\over`'s infix syntax, there's no need to create a new macro. You could simply write expressions such as

```
$a{{b}\over c}d$
```

and

```
${{ab}\over cd}$
```

(The extra grouping around the numerator term can be omitted if it contains only simple material, i.e., no commands that might affect the denominator term as well as the numerator.) Note that it's *not enough* to make `/` active and act like `\over`. It's indispensable to enclose the numerator and denominator terms suitably so that `\over` -- or any other command that acts like `\over` -- "knows" what to act on.

To me at least, the `\over`-based expressions don't look a whole lot more readable than `$a\frac{b}{c}d$` and `$\frac{ab}{cd}$` do.

Comment: It does become more readable if you define / as \over. You get things like `{1/2}b+{1/3}a` instead of `\frac{1}{2}b+\frac{1}{3}a`. But I was wondering if you could define an new command such that you can write `1/2 a + 1/3 b`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Over #1/#2{\frac {#1}{#2}}
% usage \Over stuff/{braced or single}

\begingroup
  \lccode`\~`@
  \lowercase
{\endgroup\let~\Over}

\mathcode`@ "8000

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\[ @3/2a+@5/3b \]

\[ @314/2a+@533/3b \]


\end{document}
```

> [image: over as @]